# Remove <li> directly by an onclick

Tags: javascript, html

Any way to remove "li" directly <strike>without javascript</strike> just with onclick?

```
$go .="<li id=\"go_$id\"><a ondblclick=\"g('$id'); return false;\">$title</a>
             <a onclick=\"go('$id', 'g')\">(x)</a>
    </li>\n";
```

I need it to be removed by clicking on (x), so together with my other function (onclick function in the code) to combine the remove so that that "li" will disappear onclick.

Comment: Whatever you write in `onclick` is essentially JavaScript.

Comment: Why don't you want to use Javascript?

Comment: just to have everything in onclick

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`Node.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.parentNode) to obtain the parent node and use [`Node.removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.removeChild) to remove a child node. Here's the self-explanatory version of the code:

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="var li = this.parentNode; var ul = li.parentNode; ul.removeChild(li);">remove</a></li>
```

Here's a more short version:

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(parentNode)">remove</a></li>
```

Here's how to use it in combination with a JS function:

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="remove(this)">remove</a></li>
```

with

```
function remove(link) { 
    link.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(link.parentNode);
}
```

Comment: how to combine your short version with my onclick function?

Comment: You also would want to `return false;` inside the `onclick` attribute. Otherwise `location.href` would change unnecessarily.

Comment: @Šime: the OP is free to add it. It's not strictly necessary for the functionality.

Comment: function  remove(link) { link.parentNode.removeChild(link); } for removing the li element

Answer (score 2):

No.

Not without JavaScript.

Comment: how would then I do it in javascript?

Answer (score 2):

If you chose to separate content from behavior (HTML from JavaScript), then this would work just fine (using jQuery):

```
$("li").click(function() { $(this).remove(); });
```

**Edit:**

```
$("li a").click(function() { $(this).closest("li").remove(); });
```

However, I recommend a more specific selector - like `.closeButton`

Comment: it's only when you click an (x) on that li

Comment: @Yan I updated my answer. You can use the selector `li a` to select the (x)

Answer (score 1):

```js
function remove_item(selected_item) {
        selected_item.parentNode.removeChild(selected_item);
    }
```

```css
    li {
        background: #ffe5e5;
        padding: 20px; 
        margin: 15px;
        list-style-type: decimal;
    }
```

```html
<ul id="list">
        <li class="one" onclick="remove_item(this)">React</li>
        <li class="one" onclick="remove_item(this)">Node.js</li>
        <li class="one" onclick="remove_item(this)">Dart</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If using IE, you can do it with [VBScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8104d42%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

In order to change a loaded page dynamically, you will have to use client side scripting of one kind or another (java, javascript, vbscript - depending on what browser and installed plugins).